# How to have these pictures side by side?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to edit this code to show these pictures centered side by side with each download button centered and underneath each picture, If anybody knows how to edit the code to this, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

The website link that I uploaded the code to, to test it can be seen below:

http://www.tekmillion.com/albums.html

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
.divWithBtn {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;

}
.divWithBtn img,
.divWithBtn a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<HR>

<div class="container">
</br>
 <span class="textformat1"><center><b>Albums</b></span></center>
</br>

<center>
 <div class="clear">
  <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover"      width="200" height="200">
  <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.1.zip">
   <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="images/LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT%20COVER).jpg" alt="LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT  %20COVER)" width="200" height="200" border:none;>
   <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.2.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
 </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="images/Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front     %20Cover)" width="200" height="200">
  <a href="LOVE%20%26%20HATE%20VOL.1.zip">
 <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="images/Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover)" width="200"   height="200">
 <a href="GURBET%20ELI%20VOL.1.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</center>
</br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css to your code:

This css will make image side by side.

```
.divWithBtn {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Following css will make download button below the image.

```
.divWithBtn > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Note:** And your current css which you post here is not applied. Make sure it is applied to your html element. Check path for your css file.

Answer (score 0):

add class "display_table" to outer div.

```
<div class="clear" class="display_table">
```

**add styles for the class "divWithBtn"**

```
.divWithBtn {
     float:left;
     text-align:center;
     margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

**And finally add div to the image tag**

```
<div><img height="200" width="200" src="images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover"></div>
```

**Finall output**

```
<div class="clear" class="display_table">
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <div><img height="200" width="200" src="images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover"></div>
    <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.1.zip"> <img height="50" width="150" src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton"></a> </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <div> <img height="200" width="200" src="images/LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT%20COVER).jpg" alt="LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT        %20COVER)" border:none;=""></div>
    <img height="50" width="150" src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton"> </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <div><img height="200" width="200" src="images/Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front                   %20Cover)"></div>
    <a href="LOVE%20%26%20HATE%20VOL.1.zip"> <img height="50" width="150" src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton"></a> </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <div><img height="200" width="200" src="images/Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover)">
      <div> <a href="GURBET%20ELI%20VOL.1.zip"> <img height="50" width="150" src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton"></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.display_table { display: table; }
.divWithBtn { float: left; text-align: center; margin: 0px 20px; }
```